# Python data structure's complexity/performance check

Tags: python

Is there a way to check the complexity or performance (i.e. Big O notation) of python data structure's methods offline?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: by reading cpython source code?

Comment: I want to check the complexity of methods, i.e. `list.insert()` or `list.remove()`

Comment: @georgexsh: I wish to find it without reading the source code

Answer (score 0):

If you understood what *Big O notation* means, you should be able to "measure the running times" of increasingly longer input.

Try with input size 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... and plot the result. This is a fine approximation of the behaviour of your function.

YOu should make friend with pytho's time module :)